# 'IDFA' is used as a contact key for some contacts and 'unique keys' for other contacts

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, contactbuilder, mobilepush-ios

When I go to  'All Contacts'> 'Mobile Push' I  noticed that some contacts have IDFA(advertiser ID) as Contact Keys. While other contacts have unique numbers as Contact Keys. Do you know why this is happening? How can I fix this issue and use unique keys for all contacts.

Answer (score 1):

Mobile Push does not make use of IDFA in any way.  If your application has not expressly set a `Contact Key` then a random UUID is generated and used to identify the contact.  Are you sure that's not what you're seeing?